# How to Make a PictureBox Scrollable

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll

I've 2 buttons, 1 PictureBox and 1 Panel.
PictureBox's inside of the Panel and Panel's AutoScroll property is set to "true". Also PictureBox Dock property is set to "Fill".

1. Button draws a Rectangle into the pictureBox, 2. one makes it bigger whose size is bigger than the pictureBox itself. So, I need pictureBox to be scrollable.

How can I make it? Any example for this thread?

My Best Regards...

Important: Please don't give advise using existing files! I'm not using them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do that, you need to change the PictureBox's `Dock` to `None`, then set the size yourself.

Answer (score 6):

*Disclaimer: Not tested.*
1- Set your panel's `AutoScroll` property to `true`:

```
this.panel1.AutoScroll = true;
```

2- Set `SizeMode` property of your picturebox to `AutoSize`:

```
this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
```

That should do the trick.
If you still have problems, there are some workaround mentioned in the following pages:
http://forums.techarena.in/software-development/1305463.htm
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10020769/picturebox.aspx
If you

Comment: What about the `Dock` property of the pictureBox? Should it stay on `Fill` or be set to `None`?

Comment: Haven't tested and I'm very much in doubt the first solution I have mentioned would work. But there are some workarounds mentioned in the posts I have addressed.